# Include in Makefile another Makefile with relative path

Tags: makefile, path, gnu-make

I have a directory tree like this with some "shared targets" in the file `rules.Makefile`:

```
├── Makefile
├── rules.Makefile
└── my_subdir
    └── Makefile
```

I would like to invoke these "shared targets" in both the `Makefile`(s) in the parent directory and the child directory.

Also the "custom targets" in the `Makefile` in the child directory should be callable from the `Makefile` in the parent directory.

For some reason I am able to call the targets in `rules.Makefile` only from the sibling `Makefile` (the one in the parent directory). When using relative paths in the `Makefile` in the child directory trying to access the `rules.Makefile` in the parent directory I get some errors.

The content of the `Makefile` in the parent directory:

```
RULES_MAKEFILE_PATH=$(PWD)/rules.Makefile
include $(RULES_MAKEFILE_PATH)

foo-parent:
    @echo $(RULES_MAKEFILE_PATH)
```

The content of the `Makefile` in the child directory (**please note that double dot `..`**):

```
RULES_MAKEFILE_PATH=$(PWD)/../rules.Makefile
include "$(RULES_MAKEFILE_PATH)"

foo-child:
    @echo $(RULES_MAKEFILE_PATH)
```

When calling from the parent directory `make foo-parent` then I see the expected path.

When calling from the child directyr `make foo-child` then I see this error:

```
$ make foo-child 
Makefile:9: "/<PARENT_PATH>/my_subdir/../rules.Makefile": No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '"/<PARENT_PATH>/my_subdir/../rules.Makefile"'. Stop.
```

- How can I make the relative paths work in the "child directory"?
- Also how can I call the targets defined in the `Makefile` in child directory (e.g. `foo-child`) from the `Makefile` in the parent directory?

Comment: There's more than one way to do it. Would you rather hard-code a path in the child makefile, or use Recursive Make?

Comment: @Beta hard-coded paths are not ideal, so I would prefer recursive Makes, however if these recursive Makes are too obscure/complicated to read/maintain then probably I would prefer hard-coding a path. Thanks!

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/igagis/prorab

Answer (score 2):

Well first, `$(PWD)` is not a special variable to make.  It's just a normal variable, that's imported from your shell.  So it will always have the same value everywhere in your makefile *and* in all included makefiles, it won't change just because you're including a makefile from a different directory.

Second, even for `$(CURDIR)` (which is a special variable and is set by make to be the current directory when make starts), it is never reset when you include a makefile from another directory.

And, all paths in `include` lines are evaluated based on the directory make was in when it started, not on a path relative to the currently-parsed makefile.  So if `Makefile` includes `foo/Makefile`, then `foo/Makefile` has an `include bar.mk`, make will look for `bar.mk` not `foo/bar.mk`.

Comment: It seems there is a missing part in the answer as the last sentence is truncated. Please could you update it? It's quite informative, thanks!

Comment: Actually that was some junk I left in there by accident because it was scrolled off the bottom of my editing box.  I removed it.  If the answer is not clear enough let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The point about `$(PWD)` above is true. However, if that is not a concern, you could still use the shell function to execute commands to get paths of another Makefile to include: `$(shell pwd)`

I did something similar for a project that benefited from having the same Makefile used in many places, using `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.

```
MAKEFILE := $(shell git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/makefiles/example.def
include $(MAKEFILE)
```